# Validate user provide json data against avro schema with default values

Tags: avro

I have this avro schema

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "name",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "field1",
    },
    {
      "type": ["null","string"],
      "name": "field2",
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

And corresponding json input

```
{
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2"
}
```

It passes the avro validator provided by avro-tools

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.4.jar jsontofrag  "`cat schema.avsc`" data.json
```

However, since field2 is optional if I omit that field and input the json value
as

```
{
        "field1": "value1"
}
```

it throws an exception of

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected field name not found: field2
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue? I don't want to manually add null values for the fields with possible default null values like field2 in this case

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which languages are you able/willing to use?

Comment: @mtth. I am using java

Comment: I don't think the Java JSON decoder supports this unfortunately. http://stackoverflow.com/q/35778151/1062617 faces the same issue.

Comment: @mtth. Is there any validator in other language that works?

Comment: JavaScript has one that does (I wrote it). Here's a quick example: https://runkit.com/5823ffb83bbdc700145febfe/5823ffb83bbdc700145febff

Comment: Looks like prior to this commit https://github.com/apache/avro/commit/7e4037de2a891fa738aaf8a4fc56f424d6c6833a#diff-c7934590c625ba67bf1b2ad5511a4f58R97 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-388) Avro GenericDatumReader was able to use default values for skipped fields, but no longer can do it.