# Validation Json Message against Avro Schema with aggregated error

Tags: java, json, avro, jsonschema

I am using Avro schema and want to validate my JSON message against it. I have found below for the same. But my issue is it fails as soon as it encounters the first issue, I want to get all the issues in my JSON message.

```
public static boolean validateJson(String json, Schema schema) throws Exception {

    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(json.getBytes());
    DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(input);

    try {
        DatumReader reader = new GenericDatumReader(schema);
        Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, din);
        reader.read(null, decoder);
            
        return true;
    } catch (AvroTypeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499117/validate-user-provide-json-data-against-avro-schema-with-default-values

Comment: Thanks but this also gives one error at a time.